# How to Remember User in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, authentication, session

Sorry if this is an obvious thing, but I am very new at programming. I've got my app to be able to login/signup users but as soon as I navigate to a different page in the app and then go back to a user page it acts like I haven't logged in. I'm not sure how to get it to remember that I've logged in. I'm assuming I need to pass Session data from my User Controller to my other Controller class. But honestly I'm just lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My Authentication Code

```
public static final String userSessionKey = "user";


public User getUserFromSession(HttpSession session) {
    Integer userId = (Integer) session.getAttribute(userSessionKey);
    if (userId == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Optional<User> user = userDao.findById(userId);

    if (user.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    return user.get();
}

public static void setUserInSession(HttpSession session, User user) {
    session.setAttribute(userSessionKey, user.getId());
}
```

My Login Code (Event after I login, if I hit the login tab again it takes my to the login route not the user account route.)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String displayLogin(HttpServletRequest session, Model model){

    if (session.getAttribute(userSessionKey) == null){
        model.addAttribute("title", "Login");
        model.addAttribute("users", userDao.findAll());
        return "user/login";
    }

    return "user/account";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processLogin(@RequestParam(name = "password") String password,
                           @RequestParam(name = "email")String email,
                           Model model){
    for(User theUser: userDao.findAll()){
        if(theUser.getEmail().equals(email) && theUser.getPassword().equals(password)) {
            model.addAttribute("userAccount", theUser);
            return "user/account";
        }else{
            model.addAttribute("invalidCredentials", true);
        }
    }

    return "user/account";
}
```

Sample of how I've tried to test it in my other class (really not sure if my approach is even close)

```
@OneToOne
public UserController userController;

@Autowired
private PaoDao paoDao;

@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;

@RequestMapping(value = "remove", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String displayRemovePaoForm(HttpSession session, Model model) {

    if (userController.getUserFromSession() == null){
        model.addAttribute("title", "Login");
        model.addAttribute("users", userDao.findAll());
        return "redirect:login";
    }

    model.addAttribute("paos", paoDao.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("title", "Remove Pao");
    return "pao/remove";
}
```

All I want is to login and stay logged in until I logout, I have no idea how to do it. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a store type to store the session of the user.
Their are two types of store types you can use : jdbc and redis

**For JDBC use** : `spring.session.store-type=jdbc`  property in application.properties file.

Add dependency for JDBC :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**For redis use** : `spring.session.store-type=redis` property in application.properties file.

Add dependency for redis :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

This might be helpful..!!